# Firefox html ordered list numbering messed up by sublist

Tags: html, firefox, html-lists

My sublists suddenly started breaking my ordered lists in Firefox (68.0.2) for Ubuntu, and Firefox on my android mobile.  Is this a Firefox bug or is my syntax bad here?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Ordered list item 1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>sub bullet list item</li>
    <li>sub bullet list item</li>
    <li>sub bullet list item</li>
    <li>sub bullet list item</li>
    <li>sub bullet list item</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Ordered list item #2. Why is this appearing as 6 in Firefox?</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a new FF 68+ regression. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548753

Comment: It's the [markup](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548753#c3). The sublist should be inside the `<li>` to be a sublist.

Comment: Yeah, it's incorrect (or at least ambiguous) markup. But it used to be rendered the other way around, and is rendered like this in all other browsers, it seems.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is, in your code `ul` is not inside any of your `li` tags. Therefore, list items of your unordered list are not subitems of any item in your ordered list. Try this instead:

```html
<ol>
    <li>Ordered list item 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub bullet list item</li>
            <li>sub bullet list item</li>
            <li>sub bullet list item</li>
            <li>sub bullet list item</li>
            <li>sub bullet list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Ordered list item #2. Why is this appearing as 6 in Firefox?</li>
</ol>
```